# Cuantas librerias de C existen?

Tags: c

He buscado las librerías, sin embargo me aparecen algunas que dicen estandar pero solo unas 8 o 10. Acaso solo son tan pocas? Hay alguna página o documentación acerca de eso?.

Comment: Hay muchas librerías, para gustos y colores. Cualquiera puede crearlas. No es que haya una página con todas. Se pueden distinguir entre multiplataforma y específicas para alguna en particular.

Comment: Aquí puedes consultar las estándar, con la versión del lenguaje en la que aparecen, junto a detalles y aclaraciones: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header

Answer (score 1):

Espero que mi respuesta sea clara, y por supuesto, no sea imprudente responder tu pregunta a estas alturas.

---

Primero, vamos al contenido de tu pregunta

> He buscado las librerías, sin embargo me aparecen algunas que dicen estandar pero solo unas 8 o 10. Acaso solo son tan pocas? Hay alguna página o documentación acerca de eso?.

La biblioteca estándar de C, es, según wikipedia dice:

> La biblioteca estándar de C (también conocida como libc) es una recopilación de ficheros cabecera y bibliotecas con rutinas, estandarizadas por un comité de la Organización Internacional para la Estandarización (ISO), que implementan operaciones comunes, tales como las de entrada y salida o el manejo de cadenas.

O sea, que, estas son, las que normalmente, un compilador de C, debería traer, como básico, (obvio que, tal vez algún compilador no las traiga), pero la norma es esa.

Generalmente, eso viene a definir los prototipos de las funciones (el estándar), puesto que las implementaciones de estas funciones, pueden, incluso, variar según el sistema operativo, como la función `printf`, o `puts`, que "escriben" en la salida estándar (generalmente la consola), o, las operaciones con archivos (`FILE`). En ciertos casos, estas librerías pueden ser (o parecer) suficientes para crear alguna clase de software bastante útil.

Generalmente, las librerías consisten en un archivo de encabezado `.h` y dependiendo del sistema de librerías que uses (al menos en linux, es relativamente sencillo, dependiendo de la distribución, instalar librerías para C), vienen en conjunto con alguna clase de archivos de extensión `.a`, `.lib`, etc. que generalmente se enlazan con el ejecutable (esto nos lleva a un tema un tanto interesante, [Librerías estáticas y dinámicas](http://www.chuidiang.org/clinux/herramientas/librerias.php)).

Entonces, **¿Cuantas librerías de C existen?**

Yo creo que el abanico de librerías de C es demasiado grande, hasta ahora no he utilizado muchas, es más, aún estoy intentando aprender a utilizar la biblioteca estándar por completo.

Aquí te menciono algunas librerías que a mi gusto, son bastante útiles o interesantes:

[Simple Direct Media Layer](https://www.libsdl.org/)

[Allegro](https://liballeg.org/)

[Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://www.pcre.org/)

[GSL - GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)